# Hide/Show Divs using effects Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu, hide, show

i am trying to hide main div and show another, with jquery, i coded this, but its not working.
this is the jquery and the css.

```
          <script>
 $(".mib").click(
function Mision() {
      var $next = $('#content #mision');
      var $active = $('#content .activec');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
        $active.removeClass('activec');
        $next.fadeIn().addClass('activec');
            });   
          });

  </script>

<style>
#content div {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#content div.activec {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

and here is the html

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="" class="mib">Mision(actually here goes an image)</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="intro" class="activec">Intro Text</div>
<div id="mision">Mision Text</div>
</div>
```

I revised the code, and i still cant find the error.. Please help :)

Comment: Could you explain what, precisely, is 'not working'? What's it meant to do?

Comment: It's not, it's suppoused to work when you click "mision" on the menu, but it doesnt, nothing happens. Its supposed that the div called intro is gonna disappear and the div called mision is going to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mib">Mision(actually here goes an image)</a>
```

And encapsulate your script within `ready` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".mib").click(function Mision() {
      var $next = $('#content #mision');
      var $active = $('#content .activec');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
         $active.removeClass('activec');
         $next.fadeIn().addClass('activec');
      });   
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9vvkk/)**

Comment: OMG, It is working! i missed the ready callback.. Thanks a lot! I really appreciated your answer! :)

Comment: Ew @ `javascript:void`.  Use `e.preventDefault()` instead :)

Comment: @XyanEwing Why should I use that instead?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple - http://jsfiddle.net/4KP5F/1/

```
$(".mib").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#intro").fadeOut(400, function() {
        $("#mision").fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: It works too! Thanks a lot!, the final project its a little bit more complicated that's why i need to use the class remover, i love this community, fast answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(".mib").click(
function Mision() {
```

To

```
$(".mib").click(
function() {
```

(Nevermind on the last edit, you have the right number of closing brackets.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mib").bind('click',function Mision() {
      var $next = $('#content #mision');
      var $active = $('#content .activec');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
         $active.removeClass('activec');
         $next.fadeIn().addClass('activec');
      });   
   });
```